# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}' in html

Tags: python, html, css, mysql, flask

i'm trying to make an if into my code html with flask:

```
 {% if  {{ role }}  = 1  %}
            <div id="cabecera">
                <header class="py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
                    <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                    <a href="/home" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-auto text-dark text-decoration-none">
```

i send {{ role }} from the login but when i execute the code, it say this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlsoU.png)

i'm trying to control the view with permissions, if role is 1 show a div but if is other number, show a diferent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if role == 1 %}
    <div id="cabecera">
        <header class="py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
            <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                <a href="/home" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-auto text-dark text-decoration-none">
(...)
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i saw the answer after public the question jajaja, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `{{ }}` to refer to variables inside Jinja statements. See [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#tests).

So provided you have passed a variable `role` to the template the following will work:

```
{% if role == 1 %}
        <div id="cabecera">
       etc...
{% endif %}
```